# Error: read ENOTCONN: Nodejs, error after running the project

Tags: node.js, sockets, windows-10

Node project worked fine couple of months ago, now after implementation of sockets, when trying to run the app, i see the following error:

[Error in console(git bash)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSW0K.png)

I'm using win 10, tried changing Node versions(4.7, 6.10, 7.2, 7.9), No result there.

The port I'm using is not busy.

We are using `socket.io`, tried to remove the part of code, that uses the module, but unexpectedly, it did not help.

Any ideas ?

`Update:` Works fine on OS X, and doesn't work on 3 different win 10 oter computers.

Comment: Can you try executing `taskkill /f /im node*` and then restart your machine and try again?

Comment: No, it didnt help, it.s not one computer specific, not working for win 10.

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to the error event.

```
socket.on('error', function () {
   // Error logging here
});
```

Comment: No change...

As i said, i also tried removing all the parts in the code, where sockets were used, but hat didnt help. Thanks anyway

Comment: Perhaps this would help:
`const io = require('socket.io')(); 
app.io = io; 
app.io.on('connection', function(socket){ 
 socket.on('disconnect', function(){ 
  console.log('user disconnected'); 
 }); 
 socket.on('error', function(){ 
  console.log('socket error'); 
 }); 
}); `

Comment: I did exactly what you suggest, no result.